# How to get url of the website in iframe?

Tags: asp.net

how can i get url of the website which is in iframe, when i click on any links in website in iframe it is redirect to another page in the iframe then how can i get the page url.
can u help me. thank you.

Comment: Are you trying for Back button option? Navigating to the previous page?

Comment: @geetha no i am not using back button for example in iframe i have amazon.com
when i click on any product in amazon site it redirect to another page in amazon site then how can i get the url of that page

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to make it easier:

```
alert($("#iframeid").attr("src"));
```

You can also use jquery contents() to retrieve or manipulate any tags inside that iframe. example:

```
$("#iframeid").contents().find("a").css("background-color","red").end().find("title").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't really have much control over an Iframe once it loads. I think pretty much the only thing you have control over is the ability to reload it with a new URL programatically.

If the page loaded by the Iframe is part of your website (not 3rd party), you can process the request server-side.

Answer (score 0):

From javascript?  If you can run some JS inside the iframe:

```
alert(document.location.href);
```

If you can't - need to get a reference to the iframe in question:

IE:

```
alert(document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow.document.location.href);
```

FF, Safari, Chrome, etc:

```
alert(document.getElementById(iframeId).contentDocument.location.href);
```

As mentioned - you wont be able to do this if the URL that is loaded is not from the same domain as your website.

Comment: when i write document.getElementById('myIframe').src;
it is giving site url, but when i move to another page in the same site i am not getting full path of the site every time it is showing the initial url of the site but i want total url, when i move to another page in the same site. for example in my iframe i have amazon site if i click on BOOKS in amazon it is redirect to another page in the same site, i want the url of the page how can i get the url of the page. Thank u for response

Comment: try: document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.location.href OR

document.getElementById('myIframe').contentDocument.location.href