# Request.Url when in an iFrame?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, iframe

I need to retrive the Url of an application that is iframed... 
What I have is an application that iframes another application.

For the application that's iframed I would like to retrive its Url, my question is now...
would Request.Url for the application thats iframed return the iframed applications url (the url thats in the src of the "main-application") or would it return the browser adress?

Just wanted to double check this with you guys.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589485/how-to-get-url-of-the-website-in-iframe**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Request.Url` will return the `iframe`'s Url.

If for some reason you want the Url of the page that contains the `iframe`, try using `Request.UrlReferrer` instead.